# How to cancel parse back4app get/post request?

Tags: android, performance, back4app

I am working on my android app. I am using back4app for data storage. I want to know how to stop/cancel the get/post request. Because some time internet is slow, data is not enough which causes my application to crash. How can i handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you share your current code, the line that is crashing and any logs that you have?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo there is no line crashing my app i want to know how can i cancel the request if user is disconnected or closed the application for some reason.

Comment: Do you mean cancel it of being processes on the server side or just cancel it in client side and stop waiting for its response?

Comment: Yes cancel it in client side. How can i do that?

Comment: It is currently not possible. You can follow [this](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/how-to-cancel-query-operaiton-android/625) thread regarding this.